# Java memory usage of simple data structure

Tags: java, string, memory, jvm, hashmap

I want to have a quite exact measurement of my cache implemented in java. Please tell me if this approach is possible.

I have a hashmap mapping a string to an array of string. Is there some way to get a good aproximation of this data structure?

1. How do I get the size of a string? Call String.toByte() and add some plus for the overhead of holding the object?
2. Is a string array the sum of all strings? Or is there some overhead?
3. Does the hashmap also have some overead, maybe wrapping the objects into some entry object?
4. For all unused space in the map, the hashmap still allocates some space, can I sum up `2 * null pointer` for all unsused spaces in the map?

I'm happy with partical answers aswell poiting me in the right direction.

Comment: (At least in the Sun JVM) Strings are held internally as a char[] rather than a byte[], so an approximation for the heap size of a string is 2*str.length() plus a bit for the other fields and object overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual memory overhead implied by an object instance depends on some internal details of the JVM implementation, and may be hard to *define* because it can change throughout the lifetime of the object (within the garbage collector, an object can "move" between generations which use distinct memory management structures).

A very rough approximation is that each instance of any object includes two "words" (two 32-bit values on a 32-bit machine, two 64-bit values on a 64-bit machines); one of the words is more or less a pointer to the `Class` instance for that object, the other holds some object state such as the monitor for that object (the one you lock with `synchronized`). Then there are the object fields. For an array, the array length must be written somewhere in the object, and also the values.

At that point, have a look at the source code for the Java classes (look for a file named `src.zip` in the JDK distribution). In the `String.java` file, we can see that, internally, a `String` instance has four fields: a reference to an array of `char` values, and three `int` (one is the index of the first string character within the array, the second is the string length, and the third caches the string hashcode). So, for a 32-bit machine, you can estimate that the minimal memory usage for a `String` instance of *n* characters is the sum of:

- two 32-bit words for the `String` instance object header
- four 32-bit words for the `String` instance field
- three 32-bit words for the array instance header and length
- *n* 16-bit words for the characters themselves (a `char` is 16-bit)

That's only a minimum because the `String` instance only references a *chunk* of the internal character array, so the array memory size could be larger. On the other hand, the array of characters may be shared between several `String` instances. This structures allows `String.substring()` to be very fast: the new `String` instance internally uses the same array , so there is no data copying involved; but it also means that if you have a big string, take a small substring of it, and store *that* small substring, you are actually retaining the big array in RAM as well (for a `String` instance `str`, you can make `new String(str)` to get a new instance which will internally use a newly allocated and trimmed down array instance). On the bright side, if you have two strings, one being a substring of the other, and you store both in your cache, then you pay only once for the common internal array.

Hence, even without considering all the hidden costs implied by the GC, it is quite hard to know what "memory size for a string" means: if two `String` instances share the same internal array, how do you count the "size" of each string ?

Looking at the source for `HashMap` will show you that there are internal instances which are also allocated; there is an array of `HashMap.Entry` instances, and one `HashMap.Entry` instance for every stored value. The array size is dynamically adjusted depending on the number of entries and the configured load factor.

Since accounting for the memory size is hard, an altogether different solution is to let the GC itself decide when old cache entries should be removed. This internally uses "soft references": they are some kind of pointers which the GC may set to `null` when memory becomes tight (breaking references may allow the GC to free more objects). This makes for a crude "memory-aware" cache which is automatically pruned depending on the available RAM. A useful library for that is Google's Guava and its [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) class.

Comment: thanks for the good explaination. One question concerning soft references: I heard a lot of people saying they are not good for caches because they drop information too fast and you can't control the behavior. What is your option on that?

Comment: I think I can't use MapMaker because it uses == and not equals. I can't gurantee that the string used as key is == to the string used for fetching the object again. I only know that they are equal

Comment: @Franz: Soft references used to be virtually useless because of the reason you describe. Now (Java 6 and above) they are pretty good. If you are using the server VM they are only cleared if memory is becoming scarce.

Answer (score 3):

I think a good practical approach is to use a memory profiler such as [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [`Instrumentation.getObjectSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize%28java.lang.Object%29)? This might tell you want you want, though the JavaDoc claims that it's only an estimate.

Comment: If I call it directly on the map, does it give me a shallow size or the full size including all inserted objects? If it includes all, it will walk through the complete structure which might result in terrible runtime?

Comment: As is typical for the JDK JavaDoc, it doesn't tell you important things like this. You might try testing this by comparing the values you get from an empty `Map` and a `Map` with a few thousand elements in it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Let's assume that, although it's not guaranteed (different JVM can act differently)

2) Sum of strings plus the overhead of holding an object (the array)

3) Sure, a lot. Objects are wrapped into entries, these entries are then stored into an internal HashSet, etc... Well at least in the Oracle JVM.

4) There's no "unused" space in the map... What do you mean ?

Well to sum up, unfortunately, there's NO way to get a precise answer of any of these questions. It depends on the VM, the GC, the operating system, etc... A profiler could give you some useful information related to one configuration, but that's the most you can ever hope to get.

It's by design: Java and its garbage collector want you to never have to worry about memory allocation and management details. It's awesome most of the time, in your case it's a burden. Why do you have such a need, anyway ?

Comment: Thanks, if a hashmap hits a certain size its internal structure grows, the hash function changes etc. I would guess it uses a array internally. If the internal array is 103 and if only inserted 40 object I have 63 blank spaces. Understand what I'm talking about?

Comment: The growth of the array is piloted by the load factor, which is .75 by default, meaning that when the map is 75% "full", it will be resized (doubled). The default size is 16. Both parameters can be set at the constructor. You can even use a fixed size and load factor of 1 if you know your number of elements and want to ensure a minimum of overhead (at the expense of performances)

Comment: I want to specify the cache size in relation to XMX. Using loose pointers isn't a good idea when caching because it can drop to much stuff to quickly. Catching OOMEs everywhere in the code an then dropping some objects isn't clever either. Getting a estimate of the total memory consumtion isn't accurate and needs a call to gc() first, which destroys the runtime. There don't seem to be alot of options left... :-(

Comment: I would like to leave the map as it is. I only wanted to know how to approximate the overhead of the internal hashmap structure being longer than the sum of inserted objects.

Comment: The overhead of the empty elements of the map is quite small : if your map has 100 objects, the overhead is between 25 null references to 125 null references. I'm talking references there, not objects. A ref is typically 8 bytes long, while an object has an overhead of many dozens bytes. As to your remark "There don't seem to be alot of options left", that's what I was trying to say in my answer :) The best you can do is some kind of heuristic, and keeping good error margins.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to quantify your memory usage would be to use the following:
`jmap -histo:live <pid>` (process id of your java process)

This will give you a histogram of the heap. For each Java class, number of objects, memory size in bytes, and fully qualified class names are printed.
You can also do:
`jmap -dump:live pid`
Dumps the Java heap in hprof binary format.

I would look more into [jmap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html). It is very helpful when your bottleneck is memory for java. 
For example, you can create a script that does a jmap -histo every 30 seconds. Then you can graph the output and see the evolution of memory for each object created in your java classes.

Here is one example of jmap -histo:

```
$ jmap -histo `pgrep java` |more
num   #instances    #bytes  class name
--------------------------------------
  1:    224437    27673848  [C
  2:     38611    23115312  [B
  3:     47801    12187536  [I
  4:    208624     8344960  java.lang.String
  5:     45332     6192904  <constMethodKlass>
  6:     45332     5450864  <methodKlass>
  7:      3889     4615536  <constantPoolKlass>
  8:     45671     4193136  [Ljava.lang.Object;
  9:     66203     3222312  <symbolKlass>
 10:      3889     3192264  <instanceKlassKlass>
 11:      3455     2999296  <constantPoolCacheKlass>
 12:     19754     1106224  java.nio.HeapCharBuffer
```

More examples [here](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2007/10/27/summarizing-java-heap-utilization-with-jmap/)

Also, profile your process would a good choice too. 
I would recommend using [visualvm (free)](http://visualvm.java.net/) or [jprofiler7 (not free, but awesome!)](http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files.html)